# Using .Split() to store number + number into two string arrays?

Tags: c#

Say the user inputs something like 12 + 15 into the console. Or to simplify this, 12+15.  How do I store the both numbers into different variables? 
So below obviously the console writes the input on different lines.  But I want to store both numbers in separate int variables (I know they need converting from strings, im not worried about that bit).  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Console.Write("Input numbers separated by + : ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] first = input.Split('+');
foreach (var num in first)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Comment: `var num1 = items[0]; // etc` - To learn more, look for `c# array indexing`

Comment: Thanks, this is one of those learning moments.  I knew split put the string into an array, I just didn't make the leap of using their index for further use!

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int[] numbers = input.Split('+').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

Instead of having two variables, you have an array with a length of two. Transfering to two actual variables is trivial. The code uses Linq, so ensure you include `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

The split method stores than as an array. You can then access them via their integer indices.

```
  Console.Write("Input numbers separated by + : ");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  string[] operands = input.Split('+');
  string firstNumber = operands[0];
  string secondNumber = operands[1];
```

Or you can cast them as integers

```
int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt16(operands[0]);
int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(operands[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you guaranteed to get a string of the expected format? Then

```
    Console.Write("Input numbers separated by + : ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] first = input.Split('+');
    string a = first[0];
    string b = first[1];
```

At this point you may want to rename `first` to something else...

Comment: I wasn't too worried about the input format.  I'm in the process of learning and decided to make a simple calculator.  I ended up doing this: 'string[] split = input.Split(new Char[] { ',', '\n', '+', '*', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);' to split the input and then handle the type of operator required.  Basic stuff, but practice.

Answer (score 0):

The user can enter more than 2 numbers in the console, the code below can deal with that.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] first = input.Split('+');
Int32[] numbers = new Int32[first.Length];
for (Int32 i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Int32.Parse(first[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regex` to split and put all variables into `Dictionary` as follow:

```
string input = "12 + 15 +11.5+9"; // or get from Console

string[] inputNumbers = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(input , @"\s*\+\s*");

Dictionary<int, decimal> variable = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();

for (int i = 0; i < inputNumbers.Length; i++)
    variable.Add(i, decimal.Parse(inputNumbers[i]));

// test
decimal result = variable[0] * variable[1] + variable[2]; // and so on
```

Another way is also:

```
string input = "12 + 15 +11.5+9"; // or get from Console

decimal[] variable = Array.ConvertAll(Regex.Split(input, @"\s*\+\s*"), n => decimal.Parse(n));
// test
decimal result = variable[0] * variable[1] + variable[2]; // and so on
```

Comment: Thanks, out of interest, why a dictionary, and not a List?

Comment: Dictionary is better solution when using name for variables for example `variable["var0"] + variable["var1"]`. But on the provided example List or Array is better. so I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

at the first **add:**
 `using System.Linq;`
 **then:**

```
Console.Write("Input numbers separated by + : ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int[] numbers = input.Split('+').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
foreach (var num in numbers )
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```